# Allow null for To, Cc, Bcc of mailmessage (system.net.mail.mailmessage)

Tags: c#, smtp, mailmessage

I am using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage  to capture and pass it over the info related to email.

I am getting "Value Cannot be null" exception.

My requirement is anyone of the To,Cc,Bcc can be empty but at least one of those fields should have an email (either To or Cc or Bcc).

Here is my code :

```
public object InsertMailSendQueue([FromBody] EmailReport mailMsg ) 
        {            

            mailMessage.To.Add(mailMsg.To);
            mailMessage.CC.Add(mailMsg.Cc);
            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(mailMsg.Bcc);

            mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(mailMsg.From);
            mailMessage.Subject = mailMsg.Subject;
            mailMessage.Body = mailMsg.Body;

            var confirmation = EmailService.InsertMailSendQueue(mailMsg.AgentId, mailMsg.Notes, null, mailMessage, true);
            return confirmation;

        }
```

Comment: Just don't call Add() if the string is null, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hans inferred in his comment, something like

```
bool send = false;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailMsg.To))
{
     mailMessage.CC.Add(mailMsg.To);
     send = true;
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailMsg.Cc))
{
     mailMessage.CC.Add(mailMsg.Cc);
     send = true;
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailMsg.Bcc))
{
     mailMessage.CC.Add(mailMsg.Bcc);
     send = true;
}
if (!send)
{
     // what to do if none are set...
}
```

etc. should do the job.